# Modal not closing properly

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a simple modal. I want it to close when the user clicks anywhere on the window - however, the modal closes only when the user clicks outside of the modal, even though the event target is set to the whole modal.

I know that the problem is the last line of the javascript code but I can't understand why...I have defined `e.target == modal`, where `modal` is the HTML element of the whole modal, including the children's elements (by the class of `modal-content`). However, the `modal-content` class does not seem to be affected by `e.target == modal`.

Here is the full code:

```js
//Get modal element
var modal = document.getElementById('simpleModal');
//Get open modal button
var modalBtn = document.getElementById('modalBtn');
//Get close button
var closeBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('closeBtn')[0];


//Listen for click
modalBtn.addEventListener('click', openModal);

//Listen for close clock
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', closeModal);

//Listen for outside click
window.addEventListener('click', outsideClick);


//Fucntion to open modal
function openModal(){
    modal.style.display = 'block';
}

//Fucntion to close modal
function closeModal(){
    modal.style.display = 'none';
}


function outsideClick(e){
    if(e.target == modal){
        modal.style.display = 'none';
    }
    


}
```

```css
body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height:1.6;
}

.button{
    background: coral;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0px;
}

.button:hover{
    background: #333;
}

.modal{
    display:none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    animation-name:modalopen;
    animation-duration:1s;
}

.modal-content{
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    margin: 20% auto;
    padding:20px;
    width: 70%;
    box-shadow: 10px 20px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0);
}

.closeBtn{
    color:#ff0000;
    float:right;
    font-size:30px;
}

.closeBtn:hover, .closeBtn:focus{
    color:#000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor:pointer;
}

@keyframes modalopen{
    from{opacity: 0}
    to{opacity:1}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content ="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Simple Modal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <button id="modalBtn" class="button">Click Here</button>
    
    <div id="simpleModal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="closeBtn">&times;</span>
            <p>Hello...I am a modal</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What about using target id to check if it is the modal?

Comment: or maybe try `===`

Comment: anywhere on the window including modal?? - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/gdwZzY

Answer (score 0):

You have to addEventListener to the modal for closing it on click event.
Also, some problem may appear because the events listeners are being added at the moment when page wasn't fully rendered, to fix it you have to stick to the [DOMContentLoaded](https://plainjs.com/javascript/events/running-code-when-the-document-is-ready-15/) event. Wrap the adding of the listeners into the function and call it on the [DOMContentLoaded](https://plainjs.com/javascript/events/running-code-when-the-document-is-ready-15/) event to fix the problem, please see working code snippet below:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  //Get modal element
  var modal = document.getElementById('simpleModal');
  //Get open modal button
  var modalBtn = document.getElementById('modalBtn');
  //Get close button
  var closeBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('closeBtn')[0];

  //Fucntion to open modal
  function openModal(){
      modal.style.display = 'block';
  }

  //Fucntion to close modal
  function closeModal(){
      modal.style.display = 'none';
  }


  function outsideClick(e){
      if(e.target == modal){
          modal.style.display = 'none';
      }



  }
  //Listen for click
  modalBtn.addEventListener('click', openModal);
  modal.addEventListener('click', closeModal);
  //Listen for close clock
  closeBtn.addEventListener('click', closeModal);
  //Listen for outside click
  window.addEventListener('click', outsideClick);
});
```

```css
body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height:1.6;
}

.button{
    background: coral;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0px;
}

.button:hover{
    background: #333;
}

.modal{
    display:none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    animation-name:modalopen;
    animation-duration:1s;
}

.modal-content{
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    margin: 20% auto;
    padding:20px;
    width: 70%;
    box-shadow: 10px 20px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0);
}

.closeBtn{
    color:#ff0000;
    float:right;
    font-size:30px;
}

.closeBtn:hover, .closeBtn:focus{
    color:#000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor:pointer;
}

@keyframes modalopen{
    from{opacity: 0}
    to{opacity:1}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content ="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Simple Modal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <button id="modalBtn" class="button">Click Here</button>

    <div id="simpleModal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="closeBtn">&times;</span>
            <p>Hello...I am a modal</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: he wants the modal closed when you click click on the modal